# URL validation in Zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How can i validate a url field in zend framework. I tried the following code.

```
 $website = $this->createElementText('website', 'Website');
 $website->setOptions(
            array(
                'filters' => array(
                    'StringTrim',
                    'StripTags',
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    'NotEmpty',
                    array(
                        'Callback',
                        true,
                        array(
                            'callback' => function($value) {
                                //  if (!strpos($value, 'http'))   $value = 'http://' . $value;
                                return Zend_Uri::check($value);
                            }
                        ),
                        'messages' => array(
                            Zend_Validate_Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Please enter a valid URL',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
    )->setErrorMessages(array('Please enter a valid URL. For e.g, http://test.com or http://www.test.com'));
  $form->addElements(array($website));
```

But this is not accurate. For example it is not giving errors for urls like htt://www.google

How can i improve my validation.Is there any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use a custum validator which has the advantage that it can be reused easily without having to recode it for each field.

There are many examples in the web like [here](http://www.techchorus.net/validate-uri-form-fields-zend-framework-custom-validator) or [here](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/core-infrastructure-19/how-do-i-validate-url-1269.html)  or [here](http://wiip.fr/content/zend-framework-validateur-pour-une-url) (in french) ...

After coding `Your_Validate_Uri` class you can do this:

```
$website->addValidator(new Your_Validate_Uri());
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this and my work as it should:

```
'validators'   => array(
                array(
                    'validator' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => array(
                        'callback' => function ($value) {

                            if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        'messages' => 'This is not a valid url address'
                    ),
                    'breakChainOnFailure' => true
                ),
            ),
```

---

Good Luck ;)